# TYPO3 6.2 Backend Extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am trying to build an extension with TYPO3 Version 6.2.

I build the model in the Extension Builder for 6.2.
I've added a backend module which should display the datas in the backend in the extension Manager.
That works fine but when I tried to click on the backend then the following message is displayed:

> Sorry, the requested view was not found. The technical reason is: No
>   template was found. View could not be resolved for action "list" in
>   class "SeminarCas\SemCas\Controller\KontaktController".

The Template is located under Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/Kontakt. Here are the Files: Edit.html, List.html , Show.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added it, now i tried to reinstall it and got following error:

> Please check your uploaded extension "sem_cas". The configuration file
>   "ext_emconf.php" seems to be invalid.

This is the ext_emconf.php file

```
<?php

$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
    'title' => 'Seminar CAS',
    'description' => '',
    'category' => 'be',
    'author' => '',
    'author_email' => '',
    'state' => 'alpha',
    'internal' => '',
    'uploadfolder' => '0',
    'createDirs' => '',
    'clearCacheOnLoad' => 0,
    'version' => '',
    'constraints' => array(
        'depends' => array(
            'typo3' => '6.2',
        ),
        'conflicts' => array(
        ),
        'suggests' => array(
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: How is you extension key? Isn't sem_cas?

Comment: It's sem_cas
Could it be possible that the issue is from php storm?
I've downloaded it from the backend and opened it there.
But i've removed the .idea folder in the archiv which was created from phpstorm

Comment: Your ext_emconf.php file looks valid. File .idea should not be located at your webhost. No idea, whats happend with your ext_emconf.php file at your webhost.

Comment: I've added the ext_typoscript_setup.txt now directly to the downloaded archiv without open it via PHPStorm and now it works. Any idea what PHP does in this case ?

Comment: Please ask another question in another thread, and mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Normally FLUID templates will be searched in your extension under folder *EXT:sem_cas/Resources/Private/Templates/*. If you have located your FLUID templates for backend module another place, define this in a global loaded typoscript, best would be in *EXT:sem_cas/ext_typoscript_setup.txt* with content below:

```
# BE Module configuration
module.tx_semcas.view {
    templateRootPath = EXT:sem_cas/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
    partialRootPath = EXT:sem_cas/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
    layoutRootPath = EXT:sem_cas/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
}
```

Comment: The file was not created by the Extension Builder.
Should i create i a new one with this content only in the file?
Is Fluid compatible with TYPO3 6.2 ?

Comment: Yes just add a file ext_typoscript_setup.txt with this content in your extension, FLUID is working with 6.2, therfor you get Error:Sorry, the requested view was not found

Comment: In TYPO3 CMS 8 use array syntax for path's like templateRootPath.0 = EXT:sem_cas/...